# IntelliJ IDEA not copying resources on build

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build, java-11

My build output is `out/production/classes`.
Java files get compiled into classes just fine and get put on `out/production/classes/[packageName]`, but resources aren't copied. As far as I know they should go directly inside the `out/production/classes` directory.

[image: Resources aren't copied]

If relevant, I'm using Java 11, Spring Boot and Gradle.
This is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'net.impfox'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // hidden
}
```

And my Compiler settings:

[image: Compiler settings]

What could be the cause for my resources not being copied to the output directory and how can I fix this?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/gzBDBF5.png). Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify your IntelliJ IDEA/Gradle versions.

Comment: I've had issues like this before. Try adding the following to your `build.gradle`: `idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = true
    }
}`. You might need `apply plugin: 'idea'` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was not able to find the root problem, but I've got a guess. I renamed the entire project before and replaced every occurence of the old project name with the new one. Maybe some internal cache still had the old name inside?

I ended up cloning the project from version control, now it works.

Comment: As of February 2022, I can confirm that the bug is still not resolved and re-cloning seems to be the only solution.

Comment: As of February 2023, same issue. This is distressful, lost huge time dealing with this.

Comment: I nuked `.idea`, reopened project, and after several clicks on rebuild it would now copy resources.

Answer (score 11):

If someone is having this issue in Maven. I fixed it by changing the

```xml
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

to

```xml
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

In **pom.xml**
I copied a pom.xml from a maven moduler project (in main pom.xml it uses pom as packaging). Guess I learned my lesson.